# How do I implement a realtime communication with Node JS and a Child Process written in C?

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, stdout, child-process

I am currently building a JavaScript-API that shall execute a child process (programmed in c) and both shall communicate in real-time.
(currently on a Debian GNU/Linux Server)
The problem is, that nodeJs only seems to read the stdout of my child process after it has already been closed.

Does anyone know how I can make NodeJS react to the stdout and stderr of testC.x as soon as something is writting into one of these streams without waiting for testC.x it to be closed?

A short version of my current attempts would be:

testNodeJS.js:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
var child = spawn("./testC.x");

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(`child stderr:\n${data}`);
})

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`child stdout:\n${data}`);
});

child.stdin.write( 'FOO\n');
child.stdin.write( 'bar\n');
```

testC.c:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char input_string[ 1023 + 1 ];

    printf("Start: %s\n", argv[0]);

    while ( 1 )
    {
        scanf("%s", &input_string);                     //reading stdin

        while(!getchar());                              //cleaning stdin

        printf( "Read: >%s<\n", input_string);  //write stdout

        if( strcmp( input_string, "end" ) == 0 )        //End testC.x
        {  
            printf("End: %s", argv[0] );
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

now, when executing the testNodeJS.js the desired behaviour would be for the console to print:

```
> Start: testC.x
> Read: FOO
> Read: bar
```

and waiting for the testC.x to be closed (which will not happen in this case).

But instead the console does **not print** anything. (Though still waiting for testC.x to be closed, as desired)

Now if we include the following line in the js File:

```
child.stdin.write( 'end\n');
```

The console will print the desired results, reading the stdout of the child process, after it has been closed:

```
> Start: testC.x
> Read: FOO
> Read: bar
> Read: end
> End: testC.x
```

I've already found this question which seems to ask for the same, but does not include a working answer for me:
[Reading from a stdout in real time using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045588/reading-from-a-stdout-in-real-time-using-node-js)

And due to not having enough Reputation yet, I cannot raise a bounty or do anything similar yet.
So I have to post this question to adress my problem.

And this one did not help:
[Can I check stdout in NodeJS in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683740/can-i-check-stdout-in-nodejs-in-real-time)

Comment: Call `fflush(stdout);` after you print things.

Comment: Thank you! That solution is so simple and should have been obvious to me. Searched my mistake in the wrong code.